# SwipeView gets hidden by CollectionView

Tags: maui

I'm starting to get into .Net Maui. I want to a SwipeView to the top of the page with a notification that the user can close. When I populate the CollectionView the SwipeView is is underneath CollectionView. I tried placing SwipeView into different locations but anything seams to work.

What is a good way to fix this?

I want it to look like this.

[image]

It looks like this instead.

[image]

```
<ContentPage x:Class="MonkeyFinder.View.MainPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MonkeyFinder.Model"
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MonkeyFinder.ViewModel"
         xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
         ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True"
         Title="Monkeys"
         x:DataType="viewmodel:MonkeysViewModel">


    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*"
          ColumnSpacing="5"
          RowDefinitions="*,Auto"
          RowSpacing="0"
          BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightBackground}, Dark={StaticResource DarkBackground}}">


            <StackLayout Margin="0,5,0,5"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                         Padding="0">
                    <SwipeView x:Name="swipeView">
                            <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                    <SwipeItems>
                                            <SwipeItem Text="Favorite"
                                                       IconImageSource="favorite.png"
                                                       BackgroundColor="LightGreen" />
                                            <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                                                       IconImageSource="delete.png"
                                                       BackgroundColor="LightPink" />
                                    </SwipeItems>
                            </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                            <Grid HeightRequest="60"
                                  BackgroundColor="Lightblue">
                                    <Label Text="This is a test. Swipe to close."
                                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                    </SwipeView>

            </StackLayout>


            <RefreshView Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                         Command="{Binding GetMonkeysCommand}"
                         IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                                    SelectionMode="None">
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Monkey">
                                            <Grid Padding="10"
                                                  HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                                                    <Frame HeightRequest="125"
                                                           Style="{StaticResource CardView}">
                                                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MonkeysViewModel}}, Path=GoToDetailsCommand}"
                                                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                                            <Grid Padding="0"
                                                                  ColumnDefinitions="125,*">
                                                                    <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
                                                                           HeightRequest="125"
                                                                           Source="{Binding Image}"
                                                                           WidthRequest="125" />
                                                                    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                                                         Grid.Column="1"
                                                                                         Padding="10">
                                                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LargeLabel}"
                                                                                   Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"
                                                                                   Text="{Binding Location}" />
                                                                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                                                            </Grid>
                                                    </Frame>
                                            </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
            </RefreshView>

            <Button Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="8"
                    Command="{Binding GetMonkeysCommand}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonOutline}"
                    Text="Get Monkeys" />

            <!--  Add this  -->
            <Button Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="8"
                    Command="{Binding GetClosestMonkeyCommand}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonOutline}"
                    Text="Find Closest" />


            <ActivityIndicator Grid.RowSpan="2"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                               HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                               IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                               IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                               Color="{StaticResource Primary}"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: your CV is in the same grid row as the RefreshView.  Place them in different rows

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the SwipeView and RefreshView in different rows so the SwipeView wouldn't get hidden or covered by the RefreshView(CollectionView).

So to fix it, you need to define the `RowDefinitions` like `RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto"`.

Here's the code XAML code below:

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*"
      ColumnSpacing="5"
      RowSpacing="0"

      RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto">

      <StackLayout Margin="0,5,0,5"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"

                        Padding="0">

           <SwipeView x:Name="swipeView">
                  <!--Omitted for brevity-->
    
           </SwipeView>
       </StackLayout>


       <RefreshView Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Command="{Binding GetMonkeysCommand}">

           <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"

                                   SelectionMode="None">

               <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                     <!--Omitted for brevity-->
        </RefreshView>
```

**Output:**

[image]